# Why bluez removal also removes almost all system settings?

Tags: bluez

I wanted to change bluez 4 to bluez 5.

Moving through the procedure I found that bluez removal also removes ubuntu-desktop, unity-control-center and some other packages. Do you really think I do not need so set up my system any more if I've removed bluetooth support? That's funny!

Update with details:

Ubuntu 14.04.
Run `sudo apt-get purge bluez`.
It removes ubuntu-desktop, unity-control-center and other packages, and informs that they will be removed. Of course, I can install them back (as I did), but the usability of such approach is doubtful.

So, for example, if I do not want to have bluetooth support in my computer and remove it, why do I lose system settings in addition?

Comment: "moving through the procedure"what procedure is this, what Ubuntu release is this? Please edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want bluez 5, I recommend you upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS which includes [bluez 5](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez).